# Where to put these codes when adding firebase to the react native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to use firebase push notifications in my react native iOS app.
I am not sure about this step.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

its said `Add initialization code` but when I search my react native app.
I saw appDeligate.h and appDeligate.m

idk which file to add and  do I need to add objectC or swift code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add objective C code inside
AppDelegate.m file

Keep this thing in mind that must import firebase before **FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED** this line

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

You just need to copy

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

And add it inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method